# VS 2017 Code Coverage: Exclude methods from analysis

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage

Is it possible to exclude certain methods from the VS2017 code coverage analysis?

I want to exclude simple getters/setters or simple factories (which act like glue-code) like this one:

```
public class TimeFactory : ITimeFactory
{
     /// <summary>
    /// Create a time object -> allows us to simulate time jumps in unit-tests.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IXTimer CreateXTimerObject() => new XTimer();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the [`ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to do just that.